# Можно ли присоединить пользователя к другому tcp соединению, используя текущее?

Tags: linux, tcp

Ситуация такая, что пользователь подключается к определенному адресу и порту, и я не могу управлять его клиентом-программой, то есть повторно ещё одно соединение сделать, потому что разорвется текущее соединение, и ему снова вручную придется подключится уже к новому адресу, а мне нужно, чтобы он не отключался, но при этом сначала был подсоединен к одному серверу, а потом, после того как получил с него данные, присоединился к другому, так чтобы для него это было незаметно.
Как вариант можно сделать прокси и уже с него направлять трафик то туда, то сюда. Но вариант с прокси не устраивает, потому что канал прокси перегрузится, а канал остальных серверов будет почти пустовать.
Не знаю, доступно ли объяснил ситуацию. Сейчас только начинаю знакомство с сетями, чтобы решить потом эту проблему, но даже без знаний с самого начала не понимал, как можно иначе сделать, кроме как через прокси. Получается, клиент установил соединение с ip сервера и портом, и, используя это соединение, я не могу сказать машине клиента, чтобы она присоединилась к другому серверу?

Comment: Хороший вопрос.

Насколько мне известно -- нет. 

Я знаю, что можно передать открытый сокет (файловый дескриптор) от одного процесса другому на том же хосте (через sendmsg()), но это отлчается от того, что Вы описываете.

По сути Вы хотите динамически управлять подменой dst-адреса установленного tcp соединения у клиента.

Comment: @avp, это ip спуфингом называется? Ну а если хотя бы в одном направлении слать, то есть только с сервера к клиенту. К примеру, клиент соединился с сервером A, а сервер А отослал только заголовки (или что там нужно для сверки) на сервер B, вместо отправки этого ответа клиенту, а уже потом сервер B отсылает этот ответ к клиенту, но ответ будет не пустой, а с данными. Такая реализация возможна? Или же многая нужная информация для успешной идентификации сервера B на клиенте, будет скрыта на уровнях сетевых карт и ядре ОС сервера A?

Comment: @xinakapu, IMHO спуфингом называют несколько другие действия и его я точно не имел в виду.

Вы лучше поподробней распишите, что именно хотите делать. Какой клиент, сервер.

Если клиент браузер и работает в http? Тогда может тривиальный redirect сгодится.

--

Вы же пишете так, как будто все мы знакомы с задачей и осталось уточнить технические детали.

Вот, то что вы сначала по сути спросили

      клиент соединяется по tcp и работает с серером1, затем сервер1 переключает его на сервер2 (причем клиент никак в этом не участвует) и т.д.

Без изменений в ОС клиента (IMHO) это сделать не получится

Answer (score 4):

ответ из комментария:

Насколько мне известно -- нет. Я знаю, что можно передать открытый сокет (файловый дескриптор) от одного процесса другому на том же хосте (через sendmsg()), но это отличается от того, что Вы описываете. По сути Вы хотите динамически управлять подменой dst-адреса установленного tcp соединения у клиента.